# Error when using custom query in cakephp?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have using cakephp for my website. And i use sql server 2012 with it. 
I have confused that when i use:

```
$this->set('types',$this->Manager->query('select * from product_types'));
```

to get the array of all my product types
the return array is:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => hoa my pham
        )
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => hoa my
        )

    )

)
```

Why has the [0] instead of [product_types]????

Comment: The more important question: Why using CakePHP when you dont use it for the easierst tasks at hand - and a very simple query that is. I highly recommend using it as its designed - using the wrapper method find(). And for your other questions: http://book.cakephp.org/ It is all explained very well.

Comment: Yup, but i am  newbie in cakePHP and i have more experience in writing  T-SQL so i choose this way to do :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the CakePHP documentation:

```
To use the model name as the array key, and get a result consistent with that returned by the Find methods, the query can be rewritten:

$this->Picture->query("SELECT * FROM pictures AS Picture LIMIT 2;");

which returns:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Picture] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1304
            [user_id] => 759
        )
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Picture] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1305
            [user_id] => 759
        )
    )
)
```

So you need:

```
$this->set('types',$this->Manager->query('select * from product_types as Product_Types'));
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

P.S.:

> This syntax and the corresponding array structure is valid for MySQL
>   only. Cake does not provide any data abstraction when running queries
>   manually, so exact results will vary between databases.

Comment: I do it and get no luck. But i have read your link and **P.S** is the problem for MSSQL SERVER :( thanks so much for your answer

Comment: Maybe not compatible with your db driver. Use another way to build the query

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the documentation and tutorials available.

Then you will be able to just use

```
$this->set('managers', $this->Manager->find('all'));
```

for the very same thing - using a clean approach with wrapper functions and a sql server datasource.

For SqlServer there should be a datasource available, for example:
https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/Database/Sqlsrv.php